# Is it possible to connect a mongodb/collection to email?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, email

I am building a website where users are able to make appointment requests.  The information goes to a mongo collection.  Is it possible to send the information to an email as well as the mongo collection?

In other words, whenever the db receives a new entry I'd like for that entry to be sent to an email that I choose.

I would post some of the code but I don't have any context or idea where to start.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible, but we would need more context to help you... consider checking [nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer) and maybe rephrase the question in the context of nodemailer.

Comment: it's possibile - there are also some node.js cloud solution where it's very easy. Take a look over Heroku and some AddOn to send email.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You can google nodejs send email and you will find plenty of node modules that do that.

One example is [Nodemailer](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_email.asp) module.

You will have a function where you store records to mongodb. Inside the same function, after insertion/update, you would call .sendMail function to send an email.

Comment: Thanks for the solid advice.  I was able to set up emails to be sent from the website. Follow this link for a good tutorial -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nF9g1825mwk --